# can't access helper file

Tags: zend-framework

My helper file Acl.php is in library/Helper and I have included it in bootstrap file as below:-

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

```
protected function _initPlugins()
{

    $helper= new Helper_Acl();

    // $helper->setRoles();

    // $helper->setResources();

    // $helper->setPrivilages();

    // $helper->setAcl();

}
```

}

but its giving error, Saying -> Fatal error: Class 'Helper_Acl' not found in Bootstrap.php.

Below is my helper file

class Helper_Acl
{

```
public $acl;

public function __construct()

{

    $this->acl = new Zend_Acl();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

in the bootstrap.php , try this , provided your class is in a Helper folder in the library :

```
  protected function _initHelpers() {
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix("Helper_");
  }
```

if it doesnt work tell me , there are other methods.

Comment: if, in your library folder , you follow the same directory architecture as the zend library ,it should find your action helpers or view helpers automatically , for instance Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\Helper_Acl.php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Helper_` to your autoloadernamespaces. Typically, this is done in `application/configs/application.ini`:

`autoloadernamespaces[] = "Helper_"`